# complex numbers equation

Tags: complex-numbers

i'm sturggling with the two following problems:

1) Find all complex numbers $z$ satisfying
$$|(1+i)z-2i|=2$$

2) Find all complex numbers $z$ satisfying
$$\left|\frac{z-3}{z-5}\right|=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Here is what i found :

1) : i write $z=a+ib$. Putting this is the equation i get that equation 1) implies that
$$a^2+b^2-2(a+b)=0$$
but i'm not able to simplify the solution more.

2) setting $z=a+ib$ and computing i get that the equation implies that $|z-3|=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}|z-5|$, hence $(a-3)^2+b^2=\frac{1}{2} (a-5)^2+b^2$. The problem is that it seems to lead to the fact that $a$ satisfies an equation of the second degree whch only admits non-real solutions... What did i do wrong?

Comment: While these are good questions ((+1), it is better to post them separately since the second question is not a continuation of the first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, note that 
$$a^2+b^2-2(a+b)=0\iff (a-1)^2+(b-1)^2=2.$$

Try the second one in the similar way as above, but note that we have

$$(a-3)^2+b^2=\frac 12(a-5)^2+\color{red}{\frac 12}b^2.$$

You'll get

> $(a-1)^2+b^2=8$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

1) $|z-z_0|=r$ is a circle. Transform your equality to this form, using $|z_1\cdot z_2|=|z_1|\cdot|z_2|$.

2) Think first about the solution of $|z-3|=|z-5|$. It is a line (why? which?).